# Java: getting the mouse's polling rate?

Tags: java, mouse, polling

I'm writing code which moves the mouse in an applet by sending `MouseEvent` objects for it to process. In order for my code to move the mouse from one location to another, I need to generate points to fill the path so that my mouse can move through them. However, in order to create the right amount of points (i.e., to mimic movement as if done by physically moving the mouse), I need to determine the physical mouse's polling rate so I know how often it tells my machine about its position.

I looked around for ways to retrieve this value, but the best that I found was the `MouseInfo` class, but all that it tells me is the number of buttons on the mouse and some information about its pointer - not what I'm looking for. Does anyone know a way (preferably without some sort of external dependency) to read the physical mouse's polling rate?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a solution for this in the API, but I suggest setting up a mouseListener and capture timestamps with System.currentTimeMillis() or System.nanoTime(), then just wave the mouse around for a bit and measure the time between events fireing. While you're moving the mouse, the MouseEvents should fire as fast as the mouse is polled. I think.